# Identifying matching records from tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `userSection` (questions table) which has a `userSectionId` and I may have the corresponding answer in any of the answers table `isee_answers_2013` or `isee_answers_2014` or `isee_answers_2015` or `isee_answers_2016`. The current query  have is

```
select us.userSectionId,qs.questionSectionId,qs.questionId,us.userId,
case 
when a13.correct is not null then a13.answerId 
when a14.correct is not null then a14.answerId
when a15.correct is not null then a15.answerId
when a16.correct is not null then a16.answerId 
end 
as AnswerId,
case 
when a13.correct is not null then a13.correct 
when a14.correct is not null then a14.correct
when a15.correct is not null then a15.correct
when a16.correct is not null then a16.correct 
end 
as Correct,
case 
when a13.correct is not null then a13.duration 
when a14.correct is not null then a14.duration
when a15.correct is not null then a15.duration
when a16.correct is not null then a16.duration 
end 
as Duration
from userSections us
join questionSections qs on qs.sectionId = us.sectionId
JOIN
    userExams ue
ON
    ue.userExamId = us.userExamId
left join
isee_answers_2013.answers a13 on us.userSectionId=a13.userSectionId and us.UserId = a13.userId
left join
isee_answers_2014.answers a14 on us.userSectionId=a14.userSectionId and us.UserId = a14.userId
left join
isee_answers_2015.answers a15 on us.userSectionId=a15.userSectionId and us.UserId = a15.userId
left join
isee_answers_2016.answers a16 on us.userSectionId=a16.userSectionId and us.UserId = a16.userId
WHERE
    us.valid=1 and ue.userExamId=20467
```

Could somebody please validate and say if this is the right approach or is there any other better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this logic is correct, you can probably just use `coalesce()`:

```
coalesce(a13.answerId, a14.answerId, a15.answerId, a16.answerId) as answerId
```

and so on.

The logic is not *exactly* the same.  If `answerId` can be `NULL` on a matching answer, then this does not do what you want.  Otherwise, though, it is a simpler way to express this logic.